# Bootstrap dropdown - can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the Bootstrap component Dropdown to work.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xDUR9/

Comment: have u included jquery.js? Becoz in jsfiddle mentioned above it is not included.

Comment: here a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/K6NtG/) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Please enable JQuery in your fiddle and retest.

Answer (score 2):

Add jquery to your code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kz6XZ/)**

Comment: Just found out that if you try the OP's code with Bootstrap 4 it will not work.  Bootstrap 3 is required.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and don't forget to include jQuery and bootstrap.min.js in your document.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can check out this link for live demo - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php